# Where do I replace the sqli connect code

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am looking to see where I place the mysqli replacement code so that I can eliminate the connect errors I get...

```
function DBLogin()
{

    $this->connection = mysql_connect($this->db_host,$this->username,$this->pwd);

    if(!$this->connection)
    {   
        $this->HandleDBError("Database Login failed! Please make sure that the DB login credentials provided are correct");
        return false;
    }
    if(!mysql_select_db($this->database, $this->connection))
    {
        $this->HandleDBError('Failed to select database: '.$this->database.' Please make sure that the database name provided is correct');
        return false;
    }
    if(!mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'",$this->connection))
    {
        $this->HandleDBError('Error setting utf8 encoding');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I have the following example, just not sure what I have to remove from the code above to get it to work. Any help?

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");

if (!$link) {
echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
exit;
}

echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is    great." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the second code block? you ask for help with the first and the second seems totally independent to the first as it doesn't use the function `DBLogin` nor do i see the initialization of the class used in the first code block

Comment: you missed the 4th parameter. $link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db"); in your function  $this->connection = mysql_connect($this->db_host,$this->username,$this->pwd); add db name here

Comment: @SiddhuSiddharthaRoy no actually the `$this->connection` is correct, [see example 1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

Comment: yes! example is right. but your code you are calling 4 parameters

Comment: @SiddhuSiddharthaRoy because the first block is using `mysql` while the second is using `mysqli`. `mysql_connect` does not have an argument for selecting a database while [mysqli_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) does. we need to know the relation between the 2 blocks of code as the asker is wanting help to remove code in the first block which contains depreciated functions

Comment: Memor-X that is the example I found online to replace the original code. I have the initialization in the top part that i did not post.

Comment: @fritz269 so the second block of code is from somewhere online and you want the first block of code to use the same functions shown in the second block correct?

Comment: @Memor-X yes, sorta. Like you said I want to replace the depreciated functions and this is what I found. I am supposed to replace my code with that code. If there is a better way I am totally for it.

Comment: @fritz269 i see, well then @SiddhuSiddharthaRoy is kinda right. the 4th argument for selecting the database is actually optional in `mysqli_connect` and since you are also using the depreciated function for `_select_db` you can leave it omitted and use [mysqli_select_db](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php). likewise there is also replacing mysql_query with [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: thanks...ill give that a shot.